# ESXi5 VMs are not startup in configuration of VMs startup and shutdown

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-esx

my client site is 6 ESXi5.0, 2ESX for clone servers ..in this two esx configuration one for VMA servers for Plam secure device and one for APC UPS managers.. for this esxi VMs start up and shutdown configuration are startup delay time is 1 sec and shutdown delay time is 240 sec.. 4 esxi5 for clients ..configured VMs startup delay time 3 seconds and shutdown delay time 3 seconds.. if electricity break down and re up some VMs are shutdown..not auto start up surely .. that's my problem.. thanks for urs helps

Answer (score 1):

What ESXi 5.0 build are you using? The Autostart feature was broken with U1, and was fixed again with patch ESXi500-201207001. Try to update to the latest patch level of 5.0 or 5.1.